# Primitive root modulo $4q +1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $q$ be a prime such that $ p = 1 + 4q $ is a prime as well. Show that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ ( i.e. that $2$ generates the multiplicative group $( \mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ ) .

I don't understand how to exclude the case $ord_{p} ( 2) = 2q $ .

Comment: That would make 2 a quadratic residue modulo $p$. But considerations modulo 8 rule that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the intro of Murty's paper http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~agboola/teaching/2005/winter/old-115A/murty.pdf, in particular it's explained in the second half of page 4.